# JavaScript in Mirth Connection

Tags: mirth-connect

What are the use of JavaScript in Mirth Connection 
and types of Mirth Connection routes. I am new to mirth connect and what to find out the various coding in JavaScript while creating or deploying channel.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the qestion is very broad. I try my best to make u understand shortly.

Yes mirth uses javascript. It is made with Rhino engine. Which also means you can write your program in JAVA as well as Javascript. Tool provides very effective functionality to connect from one end system to another, parse incoming data, receives acknowledgement from the end system etc.

We need to use javascript for other interoperability/storing/retriving functionality. The Javascript used is not unobtrusive javascript or framework driven javascript.

You will be given much liberty to write functions, that can be used in multiple channels, or for single channel and execute whatever you do in Java the same can be implemented via Javascript inside Mirth as well.

Here are some of tutorials to start learning how to use javascript and Mirth Tool:

```
http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Mirth+for+Dummies
http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4358193
https://amarnathks.wordpress.com/tag/mirth-beginner-tutorial/
http://wiki.patesco.ca/doku.php?id=hl7:mirth:tutorial
https://hl7engine.wordpress.com/category/mirth-tool/
```